# Ruby equilibrium index - odd usage of inject

Tags: ruby, inject, parallel-assignment

I spent a bit of time today tackling the equilibrium index problem (described [here](http://blog.codility.com/2011/03/solutions-for-task-equi.html))

After writing my own solution (which performed badly with large numbers), I decided to find one that would be a perfect score. I found this ([which Codility scores as 100/100](http://codility.com/demo/results/demoRD26JU-JYQ/)):

```
  def equi(a)
    left, right = 0, a.inject(0, &:+)
    indices = []
    a.each_with_index do |val, i|
      right -= val

      indices << i if right == left

      left += val
    end
    indices
  end
```

What I don't understand is the piece of parallel assignment and use of inject at the top of the method. Is anyone able to describe what this is doing?

Many thanks!
Stu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It assigns 0 to `left` and the sum of `a`'s elements to `right`. The 0 argument is there because otherwise an empty array would return `nil`. The shorthand used for summing is [Symbol#to_proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) and is unnecessary because `inject` directly takes a symbol as its argument - `inject(0, :+)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation @Michael Kohl. I need to read up on parallel assignment. One thing that made this extra weird is that, when I stuck a debugger after the assignment line, the values of 'left' and 'right' are both 0. Shouldn't I expect 'right' to be the sum of the vals in the array at that stage? Or is it evaluated later on?

Comment: Parallel assignment isn't exactly special. `right` should only be 0 if `a` is empty though.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a sum of the array:

```
>> ar = (1..10).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
>> ar.inject(0, &:+)
=> 55 
# or a shorter version
>> ar.inject(&:+)
=> 55
```

You should really read the [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) on the `Enumerable#inject` method. It explains everything.

Comment: The shorter version returns `nil` if `ar == []`.

Comment: Appreciate the answer on the inject part. I had read about inject, but it turns out it was the parallel assignment that made it most confusing